# Is Sweet and Low, a song referenced in Blubber by Judy Bloom, a real song?

Tags: lyrics, choral-music

I’ve always wondered because I tried looking for on Google, taking some of the lyrics in the book, but was not successful. The closest thing I found was a choral arrangement, but I don’t know who wrote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with the book, but there is a well-known children's song/lullaby of that name.  "Sweet and low / Wind of the western sea"

[Google books: 'Blubber' by Judy Bloom](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=uwl_AwAAQBAJ&pg=PA78&lpg=PA78&dq=%22Sweet+and+low%22+judy+blume&source=bl&ots=AOLnUj05dn&sig=itR0JYB9mn1T2gZnc-Mmlil-quU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjs-NOYpKzeAhVsCcAKHU-lBO8Q6AEwCnoECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22Sweet%20and%20low%22%20judy%20blume&f=false) quotes the words '...rest, rest on mother's breast...' which matches words from the second verse quoted here: [Wikipedia info on original poem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweet_and_Low_(poem)) which was set as a part-song in 1863 by Sir Joseph Barnby.

[Example performance](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t1gsn4EZpWU) : and
 [another](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Avuo4HzUlKw)

[Sheet music on CPDL](http://www0.cpdl.org/wiki/index.php/Sweet_and_low_(Joseph_Barnby))